# zsh "command not found: plugin:" for build.gradle

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle, zsh, build.gradle

I've used Maven a few times before, but I'm new to Gradle. I'm using Intellij IDEA 14.0.2 on Mac OS X 10.10.1. I also have ruby with rails installed.     "gem update"     shows that I have the latest.
I also have brew & oh_my_zsh installed and the latest.

Ok back to my problem. My purpose is to change a small project from Maven to Gradle. I created a new module for Gradle with IDEA:

`apply plugin: 'java'`

`sourceCompatibility = 1.5`
`version = '1.0'`

`repositories {`
    `mavenCentral()`
`}`

`dependencies {`
    `testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.11'`
`}`

The output when running is:

`/bin/bash /Users/lucianirimie/BCD/bcd-remote-tests/Gradle/build.gradle`
`zsh:1: command not found: plugin:`
`/Users/lucianirimie/BCD/bcd-remote-tests/Gradle/build.gradle: line 3: sourceCompatibility: command not found`
`/Users/lucianirimie/BCD/bcd-remote-tests/Gradle/build.gradle: line 4: version: command not found`
`/Users/lucianirimie/BCD/bcd-remote-tests/Gradle/build.gradle: line 6: repositories: command not found`
`/Users/lucianirimie/BCD/bcd-remote-tests/Gradle/build.gradle: line 8: syntax error near unexpected` token `}'`
`/Users/lucianirimie/BCD/bcd-remote-tests/Gradle/build.gradle: line 8:`}'`

Here is the content of my .zshrc file

`# DISABLE_CORRECTION="true"`

`# Uncomment following line if you want red dots to be displayed while waiting for completion`
`# COMPLETION_WAITING_DOTS="true"`

`# Uncomment following line if you want to disable marking untracked files under`
`# VCS as dirty. This makes repository status check for large repositories much,`
`# much faster.`
`# DISABLE_UNTRACKED_FILES_DIRTY="true"`

`# Which plugins would you like to load? (plugins can be found in ~/.oh-my-zsh/plugins/*)`
`# Custom plugins may be added to ~/.oh-my-zsh/custom/plugins/`
`# Example format: plugins=(rails git textmate ruby lighthouse)`
`plugins=(git)`

`source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh`

`# Customize to your needs...`
`export PATH=$PATH:/Users/lucianirimie/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin:/Users/lucianirimie/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/bin:/Users/lucianirimie/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin:/Users/lucianirimie/.rvm/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/git/bin`

`export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin" # Add RVM to PATH for scripting`
`export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"`
`[[ -s`brew --prefix`/etc/autojump.sh ]] && .`brew --prefix`/etc/autojump.sh`
`# Set name of the theme to load.`
`# Look in ~/.oh-my-zsh/themes/`
`# Optionally, if you set this to "random", it'll load a random theme each`
`# time that oh-my-zsh is loaded.`
`ZSH_THEME="robbyrussell"`

`# Example aliases`
`# alias zshconfig="mate ~/.zshrc"`
`# alias ohmyzsh="mate ~/.oh-my-zsh"`

`# Set to this to use case-sensitive completion`
`# CASE_SENSITIVE="true"`

`# Uncomment this to disable bi-weekly auto-update checks`
`# DISABLE_AUTO_UPDATE="true"`

`# Uncomment to change how often before auto-updates occur? (in days)`
`# export UPDATE_ZSH_DAYS=13`

`# Uncomment following line if you want to disable colors in ls`
`# DISABLE_LS_COLORS="true"`

`# Uncomment following line if you want to disable autosetting terminal title.`
`# DISABLE_AUTO_TITLE="true"`

`# Uncomment following line if you want to disable command autocorrection`
`# DISABLE_CORRECTION="true"`

`# Uncomment following line if you want red dots to be displayed while waiting for completion`
`# COMPLETION_WAITING_DOTS="true"`

`# Uncomment following line if you want to disable marking untracked files under`
`# VCS as dirty. This makes repository status check for large repositories much,`
`# much faster.`
`# DISABLE_UNTRACKED_FILES_DIRTY="true"`

`# Which plugins would you like to load? (plugins can be found in ~/.oh-my-zsh/plugins/*)`
`# Custom plugins may be added to ~/.oh-my-zsh/custom/plugins/`
`# Example format: plugins=(rails git textmate ruby lighthouse)`
`plugins=(git)`

`source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh`

`# Customize to your needs...`
`export PATH=$PATH:/Users/lucianirimie/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin:/Users/lucianirimie/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/bin:/Users/lucianirimie/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin:/Users/lucianirimie/.rvm/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/git/bin`

`export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin" # Add RVM to PATH for scripting`
`export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"`
`[[ -s`brew --prefix`/etc/autojump.sh ]] && .`brew --prefix`/etc/autojump.sh`

Answer (score 2):

Executing a Gradle build requires the installation of Gradle, or the use of a the Gradle wrapper. Take a look at the [Gradle docs](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/installation.html) for installation instructions. I do believe Gradle is available via Brew as well. With the `gradle` command properly registered on your path, you would build your project something like this (from the folder with the *build.gradle* file.

```
$ gradle build
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I installe Gralde via Brew and now I can run $ gradle build from the terminal inside the IDE. Running the build.gradle from Intellij however returns the same errors as before. I used bash in the IDEA and now switched to zsh but without a change in the functionality.

Comment: I'm somewhat confused, you say running it from you IDE works but from IntelliJ does not? Does Gradle itself work, ie. can you run something like `gradle -v`?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I was able to take one step forward after your answer, because I installed Gradle with Brew; before Gradle was on my system as a download and as a wrapper. IDEA doesn't recognise the language in the Gradle script (probably it's Groovy) and returns errors when trying to run the Gradle command from inside IDEA's terminal. Yes I can run "gradle -v"

Comment: ------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 2.2.1
------------------------------------------------------------
Build time:   2014-11-24 09:45:35 UTC
Build number: none
Revision:     6fcb59c06f43a4e6b1bcb401f7686a8601a1fb4a
Groovy:       2.3.6
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.3 compiled on December 23 2013
JVM:          1.7.0_40 (Oracle Corporation 24.0-b56)
OS:           Mac OS X 10.10.1 x86_64

Comment: My guess is the way brew set the path for Gradle did not propagate to Idea. It should be pretty unnecessary to run Gradle view the terminal integrated in Idea anyway. Idea's Gradle integration should add a Gradle panel allowing you to run tasks.